# Can I use a more advanced template for extracting $PROGRAM in syslog-ng?

Tags: log4j, syslog, syslog-ng

I am sending messages to Syslog using two Apache SyslogAppenders in Java. My ConversionPatterns are:

```
Instance-${jboss.server.name}: %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
Application-MyApp: ${jboss.server.name} - %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
```

I then have different Log4J categories configured to send different messages to either one of, or both appenders.

In my syslog configuration file, I have:

```
destination d_jboss_appli_integ {
    file("/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss/intg/Applications/$PROGRAM/$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.log"
    template("Application-$PROGRAM: $MSG\n"));
};
destination d_jboss_instance_integ {
    file("/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss/intg/Instances/$PROGRAM/$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.log"
    template("Instance-$PROGRAM: $MSG\n"));
};
```

Like this, what I *want* to have is logging to a file in `/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss/intg/Applications/MyApp/` and to a file in `/var/log/syslog-ng/JBoss/intg/Instances/${jboss.server.name}/` where `${jboss.server.name}` is replaced by the name of the JBoss server.

Instead I am getting logs written to folders called `Application-MyApp` and `Instance-${jboss.server.name}`.

Is it possible to use the template() directive in Syslog to properly extract the value of `$PROGRAM` from the messages, getting MyApp and `${jboss.server.name}` respectively?

Thanks in advance

Rich

ps: just to be clear `${jboss.server.name}` is being properly expanded everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: change the format of the messages so that the value that you want as the value of `$PROGRAM` is the only value before the first colon:

So, the following:

```
Instance-${jboss.server.name}: %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
Application-MyApp: ${jboss.server.name} - %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
```

Becomes:

```
${jboss.server.name}:Instance: %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
MyApp:Application:${jboss.server.name}: - %d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n
```

That way, the template correctly returns what I want.